# Python quicksort - List comprehension vs Recursion (partition routine)

Tags: python, sorting, optimization, quicksort, tail-recursion

I watched the talk Three Beautiful Quicksorts and was messing around with quicksort. My implementation in python was very similar to c (select pivot, partition around it and recursing over smaller and larger partitions). Which I thought wasn't *pythonic*.

So this is the implementation using list comprehension in python.

```
def qsort(list):
    if list == []: 
        return []
    pivot = list[0]
    l = qsort([x for x in list[1:] if x < pivot])
    u = qsort([x for x in list[1:] if x >= pivot])
    return l + [pivot] + u
```

Lets call the recursion metho qsortR. now I noticed that qsortR runs much slower than qsort for large(r) lists. Actually "maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp" even for 1000 elems for recursion method. Which I reset in sys.setrecursionlimit.

Some numbers:

```
list-compr 1000 elems 0.491770029068
recursion 1000 elems 2.24620914459
list-compr 2000 elems 0.992327928543
recursion 2000 elems 7.72630095482
```

All the code is [here](https://gist.github.com/3448918).

I have a couple of questions:

- Why is list comprehension so much faster?
- Some enlightenment on the limit on recursion in python. I first set it to 100000 in what cases should I be careful?

  - (What exactly is meant by 'optimizing tail recursion', how is it done?)
- Trying to sort 1000000 elements hogged memory of my laptop (with the recursion method). What should I do if I want to sort so many elements? What kind of optimizations are possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. *Why is list comprehension so much faster?*

   Because list comprehension implies C loop which is much faster than slow general way of using Python's `for` block.
2. *Some enlightenment on the limit on recursion in python. I first set it to 100000 in what cases should I be careful?*

   In case you run out of memory.
3. *Trying to sort 1000000 elements hogged memory of my laptop (with the recursion method). What should I do if I want to sort so many elements? What kind of optimizations are possible?*

   Python's recursion gives such an overhead because every function call allocates a lot of stack memory space on each call.

   In general, iteration is the answer (will give better performance in statistically 99% of use cases).

   Talking about memory structures, if you have simple data structures, like chars, integers, floats: use built-in `array.array` which is much more memory efficient than a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing a non-recursive implementation of `partition`?  I suspect that the performance difference is purely the `partition` implementation.  You are recursing for each element in your implementation.

**Update**

Here's a quick implementation.  It is still not super fast or even efficient, but it is much better than your original recursive one.

```
>>> def partition(data):
...  pivot = data[0]
...  less, equal, greater = [], [], []
...  for elm in data:
...   if elm < pivot:
...    less.append(elm)
...   elif elm > pivot:
...    greater.append(elm)
...   else:
...    equal.append(elm)
...  return less, equal, greater
...
>>> def qsort2(data):
...  if data:
...   less, equal, greater = partition(data)
...   return qsort2(less) + equal + qsort2(greater)
...  return data
...
```

I also think that there are a larger number of temporary lists generated in the "traditional" version.

Comment: you are right. It did get faster but not as fast as the list comprehension method. numbers: 1.2 for a 1000 elems list and 3.41 for 2000 elems

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare the list comprehension to an in-place algorithm when the memory goes really big. The code below get a near execution time when sorting 100K integers numbers, but you will probably get stucked in the list comprehension solution when sorting 1M integers. I've made the tests using a 4Gb machine. The full code: http://snipt.org/Aaaje2

```
class QSort:
def __init__(self, lst):
    self.lst = lst

def sorted(self):
    self.qsort_swap(0, len(self.lst))
    return self.lst

def qsort_swap(self, begin, end):
    if (end - begin) > 1:
       pivot = self.lst[begin]
       l = begin + 1
       r = end
       while l < r:
           if self.lst[l] <= pivot:
               l += 1
           else:
               r -= 1
               self.lst[l], self.lst[r] = self.lst[r], self.lst[l]

       l -= 1
       self.lst[begin], self.lst[l] = self.lst[l], self.lst[begin]    
       # print begin, end, self.lst
       self.qsort_swap(begin, l)
       self.qsort_swap(r, end)
```