# I would like explanations on python list management optimisation, and overall, optimisation

Tags: python, list, optimization, quicksort

I have difficulties understanding what costs time in python.
Specifically in one exemple, the quicksort program. Here is what is considered by several websites to be the best implementation of the quicksort in python :

```
def theirquicksort(list):
    """Quicksort using list comprehensions"""
    if list == []:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = list[0]
        lesser = theirquicksort([x for x in list[1:] if x < pivot])
        greater = theirquicksort([x for x in list[1:] if x >= pivot])
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

And here is what I would expect to be the best implementation of the quicksort (and what is learnt to us as the good implementation at school):

```
def myquicksort(list):
    """Quicksort not using list comprehensions"""
    if list == []:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = list[0]
        lesser,greater=[],[]
        for i in list[1:]:
            if i < pivot:
                lesser.append(i)
            else:
                greater.append(i)
        return myquicksort(lesser) + [pivot] + myquicksort(greater)
```

In theirquicksort, when calling the iterative lists, python (i guess ?) runs twice trough the list, taking, or not, the elements in lesser/greater.
In myquicksort, python only runs once trough the list, and thus, does nothing useless. I mean there it does not compare twice something to i.
Thus, it should, in a purely mathematical way, be faster.
And still, it is not. Why ?

Another question about optimisation, even if it matters less:
When i want to add/multiply/whatever something by something else, the "something else" depending of the condition, the usual way is to do:

```
if condition:
    a+=3
else:
    a+=1
```

For exemple.
But what if I use:

```
a+={True:3,False:1}[condition]
```

Do I lose much time ? Do I lose time at all ? At first sight there is no problem with using the first possibility, but in the middle of a calculation that could be put in one line except for this, where adding 1/3 - only a exemple of course - isn't the first, nor the last operation to be made, the 2nd possibility can be attractive. But it implies calling the dictionnary class. So, how smart is it ?

Comment: One way to profile performance of code in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html  Note that the built-in sorting methods in Python are likely to be optimised variations of Quicksort implemented in native code and will probably outperform any Python source code solution.

Comment: @Matt Coubrough
Quicksort is an exemple, here. I do not doubt the fact that the comprehensive list one is faster, nor that the in-built implementation is always better, but i'd like to understand why is it so. (i mean, the comprehensive list one)

Comment: Indeed a duplicate, apologies for it. I saw it in the related questions list, but didn't look it up as I didn't understand what 'partition routine' meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best if you ask one question per question. The first part is answered by [Python quicksort - List comprehension vs Recursion (partition routine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107790/python-quicksort-list-comprehension-vs-recursion-partition-routine?rq=1)

Then second part of your question can be expressed as

```
a += 3 if condition else 1
```

but I find that hard to read and prefer the if/then as you showed. Dictionaries for a binary test are a little overkill for the test.